# Не работает пагинация Wordpress /page/2/

Tags: wordpress

Пытаюсь открыть **вторую** страницу блога - http://localhost/sitename/novini/**page**/**2**/
Но отображаются посты с первой страницы, хотя **URL** меняется, в чем может быть дело ?

**Настроил в админке**

- На страницах блога отображать не более: 2
- Настройки постоянных ссылок: /%postname%/

Comment: https://www.kobzarev.com/wordpress/pagination-doesnt-work/

Comment: Ну я прочитал статью, это не помогло, у меня именно пагинация на странице вывода новостей не работает

Comment: Покажите ваш код вывода и вам пояснят